# Draw a list of lists into ggplot tables

Tags: r

I am getting four summaries from my data as lists like below:

```
> summary(n_elec$n_vouchers)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
    1.00     1.00     1.00     2.42     2.00 73353.00 
> summary(n_elec$mean_value)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    0.0   212.5   300.0   318.5   400.0  7000.0 
> 
> summary(n_gas$n_vouchers)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
    1.000     1.000     1.000     2.093     2.000 11932.000 
> summary(n_gas$mean_value)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    0.0   100.0   200.0   215.6   300.0  3600.0
```

I would like to convert above to a table in ggplot

```
                    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 

n_elec$n_vouchers   1.00     1.00     1.00     2.42     2.00 73353.00 
n_elec$mean_value   0.0   212.5   300.0   318.5   400.0  7000.0 
n_gas$n_vouchers    1.000     1.000     1.000     2.093     2.000 11932.000 
n_gas$mean_value    0.0   100.0   200.0   215.6   300.0  3600.0
```

I am new to R and don't have any clue how to do above? any help would be apprecited

Comment: What kind of plot did you want to make?  Perhaps you're looking for a box plot? Or are you simply trying to render a table of these summary results? If the latter, {ggplot2} is probably not the best option.

Comment: I just want to render a table of summaries.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate summary statistics for each vector stored in the list:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create example data
set.seed(1337)
n_elec <- list(
  n_vouchers = runif(5, 1, 73353),
  mean_value = runif(5, 0, 7000)
)

n_elec
#> $n_vouchers
#> [1] 42275.338 41425.964  5428.331 33292.951 27381.780
#> 
#> $mean_value
#> [1] 2319.222 6633.410 1967.821 1717.828 1022.305

n_elec %>%
  map(summary) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest_wider(value)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#>   name       Min.     `1st Qu.` Median    Mean      `3rd Qu.` Max.    
#>   <chr>      <table>  <table>   <table>   <table>   <table>   <table> 
#> 1 n_vouchers 5428.331 27381.780 33292.951 29960.873 41425.964 42275.34
#> 2 mean_value 1022.305  1717.828  1967.821  2732.117  2319.222  6633.41
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>